# Sorting 'End-to-End' like so: [[a,b][b,c][c,e]]

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

How do I sort a list of arrays like this:

```
    ((green, yellow]),
    (red, orange),
    (blue, green),
    (yellow, red),
    (black, blue))
```

so that the two elements link up end to end, like this:

```
    ((black, blue),
    (blue, green),
    (green, yellow),
    (yellow, red),
    (red, orange))
```

Comment: What's the rule that picks the starting point? You said "sort", and your example picks the one that's first in sort order, so… is that what you want? Or is it something like the starting point that maximizes the length of the chain? (If so, what happens if there are three starting points that all give chains of length 2, but nothing that gives a longer chain? Pick arbitrarily? Raise an exception?) Or… something I haven't thought of?

Comment: The starting point would be a random value of triplet[1] that has no matching parent. From this starting point:

        arr = (('ugly','green', 'yellow'), 
                 ('wolf','red', 'orange'),
                 ('dog','blue', 'green'), 
                 ('mitten','yellow', 'red'), 
                 ('elf','black', 'blue'))
                 ('sheep, 'silver', 'yellow')

I would like to create all possible lists that begin with the loners 'silver' or 'black.'

Comment: Does your code need to detect loops? (If so, what should it do?)

Comment: I want to avoid loops--each item can only occur once.

Comment: Does "I want to avoid loops" mean "there will be no loops in the input", or "if there are loops we need to detect that and raise a ValueError", or…?

Comment: There will also be variations in order, (cat, yellow red) could be followed by (monkey, red, brown) or (alligator, red, purple). I am trying to find a way to print all versions of this list, each with a different order.

Comment: There will be loops in the input, like (panda, brown, brown) can exist BUT there can only be one triplet[0]='panda' in the list, so nothing would be repeated

Comment: You keep adding more complexity onto the problem that wasn't stated in the original version, and it's still not clear we've gotten all the details. I've edited my answer to give some examples of ways you can extend the idea. Hopefully that's enough to get you unstuck on solving your actual problem. If not, maybe you need to post a new, more specific question showing where you got stuck.

Comment: Your answers have been a huge help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest-to-understand way to do this is probably to turn the tuple of pairs into a dict, and then read off the results from the dict:

```
>>> arr = (('green', 'yellow'),
...        ('red', 'orange'),
...        ('blue', 'green'),
...        ('yellow', 'red'),
...        ('black', 'blue'))
>>> dct = dict(arr)
>>> result = []
>>> key = min(dct)
>>> while key in dct:
...     result.append((key, dct[key]))
...     key = dct[key]
>>> print(result)
[('black', 'blue'), ('blue', 'green'), ('green', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'red'), ('red', 'orange')]
```

---

This will end as soon as it finds a second value in one pair that isn't a corresponding first value in another pair, which I think is the rule you're looking for. But if there can be loops in your input data, it will loop forever. To fix that, you can keep a set of keys used so far and break if you find a repeat:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> while key in dct:
...     if key in set: break
...     result.append((key, dct[key]))
...     seen.add(key)
...     key = dct[key]
```

---

That `min(dct)` picks the first element in sorted order. If you want to pick something different, you obviously need something different. Here are some examples:

```
successors = {succ for prev, succ in arr}

# Any arbitrary key that starts a chain
key = next(key for key in dct if key not in successors)

# Specifically a random key from among those that start a chain:
key = random.choice(dct.keys() - successors)
```

Comment: Good solution, but you'll probably need a more robust way to find the starting value than `min(dct)` :P

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Why? That seems to be the rule that picked out `black`. Plus, if the rule were something like "pick the value that maximizes the length of the chain, choosing arbitrarily if there are multiple maximal chain", I don't think the OP would have referred to it as "sorting". But I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, that's how I interpreted the question. But you may be right. Let's wait and see if the OP is happy with it, I suppose.

Comment: Would it still be possible to turn them into a dict if they each contain three elements? For example: arr = (('ugly','green', 'yellow'), ('wolf','red', 'orange'), ('dog','blue', 'green'), ('mitten','yellow', 'red'), ('elf','black', 'blue'))

Comment: @NathanTurczan What would be the rule in that case? I assume it's something like each `triplet[2]` points to the next `triplet[1]`, in which case you could just make a dict `{triplet[1]: triplet for triplet in arr}`, and then do `result.append(dct[key])` and `key = dct[key][2]`, or similar.

Comment: @NathanTurczan Or, probably more readably: `animal, color, nextcolor = dct[key]` then `result.append(animal)` then `key = nextcolor`.

Comment: @abarnet thank you for your helpful answer! I hope you won't mind a follow-up question: How would I go about printing all possible versions of the chain that begin and end with 'loners' (that is, values that have no matching partner)? Basically, beginning with a triplet[1] with no parent and ending with a triplet[2] with no child?

Comment: @NathanTurczan Well, _every_ chain ends with a loner (unless loops are allowed?). So, just identify the start-loners by iterating the dict, then for each one generate the chain from there.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you will need to assume that there are only two unique colors, i.e., colors that don't repeat so they can't link up. It also seems that all tuples are unique, so if a color appears twice it appears once first and once second. So let's assume you know which tuple which contains a unique element you want to start with, then you can just loop through and add the next tuple that contains the color that repeats.

```
tuples = [('green', 'yellow'),('red', 'orange'),('blue', 'green'),('yellow', 'red'),('black', 'blue')]

sorted_tuples = [tuples[4]]

def sort_tup(original_tup,sort_tup):
    for x in original_tup:
       if sort_tup[-1][1] == x[0]:
            return x

while len(sorted_tuples) < 5:
   sorted_tuples.append(sort_tup(tuples,sorted_tuples))
```

This ugly, but without more structure on the problem I think it is a fairly straightforward way to address it.

Comment: Not a fan of this solution. This has a quadratic run time complexity, whereas you could easily achieve a linear run time by storing the tuples in a dict like abarnert's solution does.